# CSS Layout Issue - Position Sidebar Over Wrappers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

This is driving me nuts but I'm trying to position a sidebar over page wrappers. The problem with absolute positioning is that the sidebar needs to be aligned with the corner of the header (blue). I thought about JS to keep it in the current position, and also calculate the height but I wasn't sure if that was the most efficient method. I'm open to ideas, Here's a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmh4B/) (you'd have to zoom out), code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    *       {margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; font-size: 42px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
    .global {width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}

    #slider {height: 354px; width: 100%; max-width: 1400px; min-width: 1200px; height: 100%; min-height: 354px; background-color: red;}
    #container      {position: relative; background-color: beige;}

    #headerWrapper  {height: 200px; background-color: aqua;}
    #header         {height: 200px; background-color: blue;}

    #contentWrapper {height: 300px; background-color: black;}
    #content        {height: 300px; background-color: pink;}

    #listingWrapper {height: 500px; background-color: green;}
    #listings       {height: 500px; background-color: orange;}

    #footerWrapper  {height: 200px; background-color: cyan;}
    #footer         {height: 200px; background-color: grey;}

    #sidebar        {background-color: yellow; width: 240px; height: 170%; position: absolute; left: 2.5%; top: 0;}
</style>

<div id="headerWrapper">
    <div id="header" class="global">
        Header
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div id="slider">
        Slider
    </div>

    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="content" class="global">
            Top Content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="listingWrapper">
        <div id="listings" class="global">
            Bot Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footerWrapper">
    <div id="footer" class="global">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Theoritically, the sidebar would start at the top left corner of the dark blue header, over the slider, and stop at the footer. It shouldn't leave the global `width: 1200px;`. With a position absolute, it muddies the waters, and if I add a relative container with a static width, I lose the other container background colors.

Comment: Why not just make `left: 0;` instead of `left: 2.5%`

Comment: I need it to stop at the dark blue header, so that it doesn't leave the `width: 1200px;` :/ not a fluid design unfortunately. So people with bigger screen won't see the sidebar aligned correctly. I'll clarify in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't leave the width: 1200px;`. It's in the center for desktop version. Sorry, I am having trouble understanding your question

Comment: Yeah, my overall layout has a `width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;` so it should appear center on certain desktops. I apologize if my question wasn't clear I wasn't sure how to explain it exactly. If you zoom out of the JSFiddle I posted above, you can kind of get an idea of what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found but I'll leave it open to see if anybody else has an idea. What I'm doing is getting the offset of my header then moving the sidebar according to my headers offset left. I do this whenever the document loads or if the user resizes their screen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offset = $('#header').offset();
    $('#sidebar').css('left', offset.left+'px');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var offset = $('#header').offset();
    $('#sidebar').css('left', offset.left+'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jmh4B/2/

```
 #sidebar   
 {
    left: 0;
 }
```